# How can I find an American university that has an education department that appreciates homeschool?

Tags: graduate-school, united-states, education

I feel that most often the master's programs in education focus only on instructor-led curricular learning.  How can I find a school in the U.S. that offers masters degrees in education that emphasize homeschool with findings/recommendations for self-study as being more beneficial for students over regular schools?

Comment: Do you mean taking the degree as an external student, or a Master's Degree in Education focusing on *teaching* homeschool students/distance education? The two are very different, and the latter has become a lot more relevant since Covid happened, while many institutions were forced to allow the former due to pandemic lockdowns and restrictions.

Answer (score 3):

Since homeschooling is a bit of a political hot potato, I suggest you research masters programs at conservative / religious univertities that are homeschool-friendly, for example:

[Liberty University](https://www.liberty.edu/education/masters/) (Baptist) - because the university is [homeschool-friendly](https://www.liberty.edu/online/homeschool-students/).

[Brigham Young University](https://education.byu.edu/deans/degrees_programs_offered.html) (LDS) - [same thing](https://is.byu.edu/support/educators/home-school).

[Biola University](https://www.biola.edu/degrees/g/education-ma) (Christian)

[University of Dallas](https://udallas.edu/constantin/academics/programs/education/4plus1/index.php) (Roman Catholic)

[Houston Baptist University](https://hbu.edu/college-of-education-and-behavioral-sciences/department-of-teaching-and-learning-sciences/graduate-program-campus-med-master-of-education/)

[Regent University](https://www.regent.edu/program/masters-in-education-med-degree-programs/)

[LeTourneau University](https://www.letu.edu/academics/education/med-teaching-learning.html)

etc - you see the pattern. If the university's web site has resources for homeschoolers, then it is more likely that the M.Ed. program might also be homeschooler friendly. Having identified some universities, youcontact them by e-mail, identify your potential interest in the masters program, and pose your questions. If you don't get responses that you like, then you look elsewhere.

For obvious reasons, you should double-check that the programs have the accreditation that you want. Expect that having one of these names on your CV will be viewed very negatively by people on the other side of the political spectrum who might be making hiring decisions.